# Markendeya’s Mrutyunjaya Stotram (not Mantra) is in which purana and which adhyaya?

Tags: puranas, stotra, markandeya-purana

The following mrutyunjaya stotram claims to be by Markendeya rishi. There are multiple versions available on the Internet. [Some](https://shaivam.org/scripture/English-Script/1743/mahaa-mrityunjaya-stotram) have 18 Anushtup (4 padas  of 8 aksharas in each verse). Others have 8 Anushtup shlokas and 8 verses of chandrashekharashtaka that appear to have 2 padas of 18 aksharas in each verse, but they don’t appear to be dhruti chanda. They all claim to be from markendeya purana, but I couldn’t locate any in the [purana text here](https://archive.org/details/markandeyapurana/mode/2up).

Does anyone know which adhyaya in which purana can one find mrtyunjaya stotram that praises Lord Shiva? i understand there is another stotram with Lord Vishnu as savior in Padmapurana also, but I am looking for the Lord Shiva version.

Thanks in advance!